# How to assign a parameter in tsx?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I got a problem and VSCode doesn't find any errors but my browser does. The browser tells me to assign it to a parameter but I don't know if I'm just doing it wrong but after typing (parameter) before the props inside the constructor it throws errors at me. Maybe you know a solution to this problem. Thanks in regards. (Explanation of what I am doing: I want to toggle 2 flexBoxes through buttons and make them visible/invisible.
I'm using react 16.13 and typescript 3.9.7. It worked quite well but after adding the second toggle, the described problem appears)

"Argument of type '{} | Readonly<{ any: "showContent"; showMessages: any; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ showContent: any; showMessages: any; } | Readonly<{ showContent: any; showMessages: any; }>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ showContent: any; showMessages: any; } | Readonly<{ showContent: any; showMessages: any; }>'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<{ showContent: any; showMessages: any; }>': 'showContent', 'showMessages'"

```
class Explore extends React.Component<{}, IState> {

    constructor(props: {} | Readonly<{ any: 'showContent' , 'showMessages' }>) {
        super(props);
        
        this.toggleContent = this.toggleContent.bind(this)

        this.toggleMessages = this.toggleMessages.bind(this)

        this.state = {
            showContent: false,
            showMessages: false
        }
    }
    toggleContent(event: { preventDefault: () => void}) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            showContent: !this.state.showContent
        })
    }

    toggleMessages(event: { preventDefault: () => void}) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            showMessages: !this.state.showMessages
        })
    }
    render() {
        
        const { showContent } = this.state
        const { showMessages } = this.state
```

Comment: How about when you change the types to `boolean` ?

Comment: May you tell me where I should change the types?

Comment: Keep your question to the point and paste only relevant codes. Pasting your whole component file discourage users to read it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Got it and deleted everything unnecessary. Hopefully this helps <3

Comment: In the interface, of course.